# My Swedish keyboard is set to English in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 this morning and I cannot get back my Swedish keyboard, even though I did have the Swedish keyboard in the setting.

Any clue on how I can get it back?

Comment: Does `setxkbmap se` do the trick?

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution above did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

System Settings - Text entry - verify that Swedish is here. 
Thats how I solve English and Czech keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Pick your keyboard and go to `Layouts` then click on `Add` where you can add the language and layout you want to your keyboard.

Once back to your keyboard screen, select the current language of your keyboard and click on `Remove` to get rid of  it, and you are done.

This is the simplest graphical and friendly solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. I have only Swedish keyboard installed. But after boot/log-in the layout is English. I have the indicator applet in my status bar and it shows "Sv" from the beginning. Clicking on it and select "Swedish" (which is my only choice and also already marked as selected) changes the layout to Swedish. But I have to do this for every session.